# Sort PivotTable values descending order in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, plot

I have a Pivot table that is plotted into a vertical plot that leaves gaps in between the bars.

[image: Text]

I would like to sort the values for each month 'DATE' in descending order so the Plot leaves no gaps in between:

[image: Text]

I have tried to sort_values() before and during the plotting, which didn't work.

It might be related to sorting by levels in a multi-index (also tried) or to reindex, but I can't get it to work.

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

df = pd.DataFrame(
    {"CATEGORY": ["A", "B", "C", "C", "E", "F", "G", "D", "I", "B"],
     "DATE": ["2021-06-17", "2021-06-28", "2021-07-01", "2021-06-06", "2021-06-22","2021-07-15","2021-06-12","2021-06-02","2021-07-24", "2021-06-21"],

     "COUNT": [200, 350, 150, 350, 400, 250, 200, 150, 325, 300]}
)

df['DATE'] = pd.to_datetime(df['DATE'])
# Format the Date in Months
df['DATE'] = df['DATE'].dt.strftime('%B')
#Pivot table with SUM and filling the NaN values with zero
test=pd.pivot_table(df, values='COUNT', index='DATE', columns='CATEGORY',
            aggfunc=np.sum).fillna(0)
print (test)
#GetLvl=test[["A", "B"]].columns.get_level_values(0)
#SortLvl=test.sortlevel(["CATEGORY", "COUNT"], ascending=[True, False], sort_remaining=False)

fig=plt.figure()
ax=test.plot(kind='bar', legend=False)
plt.show()
plt.close()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get the expected result, in this solution the idea is to draw different plots (one for each value of Date) next to each other. It is done for 2 subgroups (June and July) but can be generalized easily.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

# definition of df
df = pd.DataFrame(
    {"CATEGORY": ["A", "B", "C", "C", "E", "F", "G", "D", "I", "B"],
     "DATE": ["2021-06-17", "2021-06-28", "2021-07-01", "2021-06-06", "2021-06-22","2021-07-15","2021-06-12","2021-06-02","2021-07-24", "2021-06-21"],

     "COUNT": [200, 350, 150, 350, 400, 250, 200, 150, 325, 300]}
)
df['DATE'] = pd.to_datetime(df['DATE'])
# Format the Date in Months
df['DATE'] = df['DATE'].dt.strftime('%B')

# group by Date & Category and add the values in Count for each (Date/Category)
grouped_df = df.groupby(['DATE', 'CATEGORY']).agg({'COUNT':['sum']})
# sort by Count separately inside each subgroup of Date (multi-index)
grouped_df = grouped_df.sort_values(['DATE', ('COUNT','sum')], ascending=[0,0])
# drop the line with label 'sum' in the multi-index (2nd level)
grouped_df.columns = grouped_df.columns.droplevel(1)

dfg = {}
# extract the df for the subgroup concerning each value of Date
dfg['June'] = grouped_df.loc[('June')].reset_index()
dfg['July'] = grouped_df.loc[('July')].reset_index()

# for each subgroup, get the ordered list of the Category 
order1 = dfg['July']['CATEGORY']
order2 = dfg['June']['CATEGORY']

# create an 'ax' for each subgroup (here June and July)
# the width of each plot depends on the number of bars in each plot (here 7 and 3)
fig, (ax1, ax2) = plt.subplots(1, 2, sharey=True, figsize=(5, 9),
                               gridspec_kw={'width_ratios': [3/7, 1]})

# to have the same color for a given Category on all plots
palette = dict(zip(list('ABCDEFGHI'), ['C'+str(i) for i in np.arange(9)]))
color1 = [palette[x] for x in dfg['July']["CATEGORY"]]
color2 = [palette[x] for x in dfg['June']["CATEGORY"]]

# draw the barplots in each ax
ax1.bar(x=dfg['July']["CATEGORY"], height=dfg['July']["COUNT"], color=color1) 
ax2.bar(x=dfg['June']["CATEGORY"], height=dfg['June']["COUNT"], color=color2)  

# some cosmetics to get the plot expected
ax1.spines['top'].set_visible(False)
ax1.spines['right'].set_visible(False)
ax2.spines['top'].set_visible(False)
ax2.spines['left'].set_visible(False)
ax2.spines['right'].set_visible(False)
ax2.get_yaxis().set_visible(False)
ax2.set(ylabel=None)
ax1.set(xlabel='JULY')
ax2.set(xlabel='JUNE')
plt.setp(ax1.patches, width=1.0) 
plt.setp(ax2.patches, width=1.0) 

plt.show()
```

Output:

[image]

Comment: Thank you @rehaqds for your answer, much appreciated. However, I have not been able to run it. I get a KeyError: 'DATE' after counting separately inside each subgroup.
This line: grouped_df = grouped_df.sort_values(['DATE', ('COUNT','sum')], ascending=[0,0])
On the other hand, would you happen to know if it would be possible to do it without having to use the seaborn library?
Thank you in advance.

Comment: @Jsankari, I have just updated the code with 2 changes. 1- I included the full definition of the data (df) to get a full running code 2- I removed seaborn as per your request to use only Matplotlib

Comment: I have found the issue  with my code not running after line 19. I was using Matplotlib version: 1.5.2. Upgrading it, solved the issue. Thanks again @rehaqds